# Problem with FTP permissions

Tags: server, permissions, vsftpd

We have a folder named FTP. I created a group and gave it permissions like this

```
sudo chown :group /ftp

sudo chmod 755 /ftp
```

and then grant that group to me and the other users. I don't know why, but if a user creates a directory I can't upload to it and things like that.

Can someone please tell me how can I set up permissions correctly so a group of users can FULLY access a folder? Upload, delete, etc.

Comment: `sudo chown :group /ftp`? That is wrong. where is the username?

Comment: 755 would mean owner has full access, but *group* only has read and execute. That would explain why upload does not work...

Comment: @Rinzwind Shouldnt that mean that the group has that with every user?

Comment: @vidarlo What should i use to full permissions instead of 755?

Comment: If you want *sub*directories that are created by users to inherit the group ownership `:group` then you need to set the `SETGID` bit on `/ftp`. Otherwise, they will be owned by the user who creates them. See for example [How do I give files and directories created by FTP the correct permissions for Apache to read and write them?](https://superuser.com/a/941027)